# SQL Server - report on queries that have generated errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to be able to find queries that have been sent to our SQL Server that contain invalid statements, primarily those which include references to missing tables, view and columns, or which try to query resources that the connection's credentials do not have permissions for.

Is there a log or sys schema view that records such queries?

Comment: [Identifying failed queries with extended events](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/identifying-failed-queries-with-extended-events)

Comment: @Larnu why not post that as the answer. It's correct.

Comment: Link only answers are very frowned upon on Stack Overflow, @GrantFritchey . And I don't want to plagiarise Andrew's work. We both know that SSC has a great community, so honestly if the OP has difficulty implementing the solution there, they would be way better off commenting on the the forum there for that article. Considering the blog posts you've been making on XE recently (I *still* need to finish reading through those myself), wouldn't be surprised if he gets a reply from you there! :)

Comment: I figured a little explanation and then a link to Andrew's post would be all that's needed. It's all cool. I just figured it would work better as an answer than a comment. More likely to be authoritative. Either way. I'm easy. Thanks for the kind words and thanks for sharing.

Comment: I don't get to delve into XE much, unfortunately, @GrantFritchey, so although I could likely implement the article, I would be truly awful at explaining it! :)

Comment: If one of you doesn't post it as an answer, I'll just have to do it and steal the credit from both of you..... :-)

Comment: Have at it @NeilMoss

Comment: Turns out I'm not that shameless, though I tried. I'll add another link though for those wanting to do this on Azure: [Reading Extended Event Files for an Azure SQL Database in a Storage Account](http://davebland.com/reading-extended-event-files-for-an-azure-sql-database)